# Laravel Only display first 5 array

Tags: php, laravel-5

$reviews has 10 arrays and I am trying to only display the first 5. This is what I have come up so far.

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
@foreach ($reviews as $reviews; i++)
    <p>Body</p>
@endforeach
@endfor
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: please post the review array... Your code is wrong.

Comment: foreach didn't work in the way you did

Comment: If it's an array rather than  collection: `@foreach (array_slice($reviews,0,5) as $reviews)`

Comment: Are you high or something? Use `$reviews[$i]` if you're using for loop already. You may encounter undefined index error in case you don't have enough items in an array, in that case use `$key=>$reviews` in foreach and `break` if `$key == 4`

Answer (score 7):

Just use the take method and run a foreach loop, like so

```
    @foreach($reviews->take(5) as $review)
        <p>{{ $review->body }}</p>        
    @endforeach
```

I think that is much simpler and cleaner

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using `Collections` you could use the `take` method (see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-take)) method:

> $collection = collect([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
>
> $chunk = $collection->take(3);
>
> $chunk->all();
>
> // [0, 1, 2]

Usage

```
$reviews2 = $reviews->take(5);
@foreach ($reviews2 as $review)
    <p>{{ $review->body }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@if` to limit the loop inside `@foreach`

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
    @foreach ($reviews as $review)
        {{$i++}}
        @if ($i < 1)
            <p>Body</p>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endfor
```

Comment: I have updated it @RishiRaut, thank you for taking my attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have written the wrong syntax of `foreach`

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
@foreach ($reviews as $review)
    <p>Body</p>
    @if ($i == 5)
        break;
    @endif
    <?php $i++; ?>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking .

> Any idea why this isn't working?

Because you have syntax error here `i++`

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
  @foreach ($reviews as $key=>$values)
    <p>{{$i}} : Body</p>  
  @endforeach
@endfor
```

Note : changed `$reviews` row value as `$values`